# Dart Unit Testing: how to specify that I does not care about a certain value?

Tags: unit-testing, dart, stream

Imagine I have a stream that emits strings. I care about only second emission's value for a certain unit test and the first one isn't important.

I came up with

```
expect(stream.skip(1).first, completion("Value I care about"));
```

But is there a matcher for `emits*` method that actually says that any value is OK?

I want to write something like that:

```
expect(stream, emitsInOrder([any, "Value I care about"]));
```

But it fails with `any`.

Answer (score 0):

Should have used `anything` from `core_matchers.dart` instead of `any` from `mock.dart`. It solved the problem, works as expected.